# Disallow include empty braces into nested object - Typescript typing level

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have following Object

```html
const obj = {
    key1: { key2: 'string 1', key3: 'string 2', key4: {} },
    key5: { key6: 'string 4' },
    key7: 'string 5',
    key8: 'string 6',
  };
```

I need to do Typescript restriction which does not allow to include empty braces so in case of **key4** it should throw typescript error. The object can be different so it should be generic.

I have already done another restrictions which allows variables to be only string or object (but I dont know how to restrict only to objects with properties).

```
export type TObjectType<T> = {
  [key: string]: string | ((arg: string) => string) | TObjectType<T>;
};
```

The example function

```
const exampleFn = <T,>(obj: TObjectType<T>):TObjectType<T> => {
    return obj;
  };
```

Is there possibility to do this without JS code, but just Typescript declarations?

Comment: You would need a helper function to do inferencing for this to work.

Comment: Could you throw an example? What do you mean helper function? I Need to do this on type definition level.

Comment: Sure: https://tsplay.dev/mqeAdm